# Unable to get values from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am learning about Unit of work, repository and service. Now I don't know why the values entered seems to be null while login in screen

After values are entered when i give submit it shows only null in values screen

while breakpoints in controller i found that there is null.

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Model;
using ClassLibrary1;
namespace Registeration.Controllers
{
    public class DbController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Db
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Service obj = new Service();
            var lis = obj.GetAllLogins();
            return View(lis);
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Mdl Obj)
        {
            Service obj1 = new Service();
            var details = obj1.CreateEmp(Obj);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public ActionResult Login()

        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string userName, string dpt)
        {
            Service obj = new Service();
            var res = obj.Login(userName, dpt); //values shows null
            if (res != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Service Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using DataAccess;
using DataAccess.UoW;
using Model;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Service
    {
        private readonly Unit _uow;
        public Service()
        {
            _uow = new Unit();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Mdl> GetAllLogins()
        {
            var logins = _uow.Register.GetAll().ToList();
            if (logins.Any())
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Table_1, Mdl>();
                });

                IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                var dest = mapper.Map<List<Table_1>, List<Mdl>>(logins);
                return dest;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public Mdl Login(string userName,string dpt)
        {
            var logins = _uow.Register.Get(x=>x.Name==userName && x.Deprmt==dpt);
            if (logins != null)
            {
                var obj1 = new Mdl();
                if (logins.Id > 0)
                    return obj1;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Model
{
    public class Mdl
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Deprmt { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `_uow.Register.Get(x=>x.Name==userName && x.Deprmt==dpt);` returns null which seems that you don't have any similar logins in your data store

Comment: why you use UoW, you still use new keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown you view code here, If it on login[POST] method then, it may be possible you are not using name attribute in your html control.

Controls should have the same name as your params(userName, dpt) so that ModelBinder can bind them.

Comment: Now i am using same name as in model, values had been taken. but know it didn't compare data in database and returns output